# is there any Possibility that i could Load a document or pdf file in picturebox control in Visual studio ???if so how?

Tags: c#, file-upload, picturebox

I tried  Upto this ... but not sure how to proceed... i just want the
 file to be in the picturebox(picturebox1)...and to save it in sql 
 server(2005) and also retrieve the same ...is it possible to load 
 documents in picturebox...??? if not what control should i use to do 
 the same??

```
private void btnaddattach1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
                if (btnaddattach1.Text == "ADD")
                {
                    open.Filter = "Images Files(*.jpeg; *.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.docx; *.pdf) | *.jpeg; *.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.docx; *.pdf";
                    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {


                        FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(open.FileName);
                        if (finfo.Length < 2147483647)
                        {
                            byte[] imagearray = new byte[finfo.Length];
                            finfo.OpenRead().Read(imagearray, 0, (int)finfo.Length);
                            string imagedata = Convert.ToBase64String(imagearray);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("File too Large...", CPublic.messagename, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your database table with 2 columns first for File storage and second for its type (for file name or type)
FileStore column datatype must be VARBINARY(MAX)
and For file type will be varchar

for save and retrive file from databse you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259037/upload-download-file-from-sql-server-2005-2008-from-winforms-c-sharp-app) link

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't work. You cannot just read the document as bunch of bytes and display that. You need a special control to display the corresponding document type, such as the acrobat reader Ocx control for pdf. You can save stuff to the database this way, though.

Comment: It's a long time since I used this, but I think you just need to link the corresponding com object. Go to "add references", select the COM tab and look for something that says "adobe ocx control" or similar. After that, the control should show up in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer in short you can't. As per the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) the supported formats are BMP, GIF, EXIG, JPG, PNG and TIFF.

Note: There seem to be a number of [converters](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=bHx8UvmwK8GOrQeMn4DIAQ#q=pdf%20to%20image%20converter) to be found through Google, that might help you out. 
You can try this

Comment: Go through this link to know how to [displays a PDF file](http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.in/2012/03/wpf-interop-com-activex-ocx-and-pdf-fun.html) with  ActiveX OCX